# Where is Édouard Lucas' grave?

Tags: 19th-century, famous-people

Where is buried [Édouard Lucas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89douard_Lucas)?

He was a famous French mathematician, he died in 1891 in Paris, France.

His full name is: François-Édouard-Anatole Lucas

I tried a search on the findagrave website, but there is no entry for his name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since he died in Paris, it is quite probably that he was buried there:

> Lucas died at the age of 49  (3 October 1891)  from a severe infection following a freak accident:  A waiter had wounded his cheek with a broken plate at a banquet of the  Association française pour l'avancement des sciences  (AFAS).  Edouard Lucas is buried in  Montmartre Cemetery.
>
> — Gérard P. Michon: ["Numericana's Biographies"](http://www.numericana.com/fame/bio.htm)

[Montmartre Cemetery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montmartre_Cemetery) is officially called "Cimetière du Nord":

> Édouard Lucas (1842–1891), mathematician

More specifically:

> [image] [image]
>
> The tomb of Édouard Lucas on the Montmartre cemetary, Paris: 770cp1857, 23rd division, 8th row, 27 Avenue des Carrieres
>
> — Caroline Holz auf der Heide: "Distances and automatic sequences in distinguished variants of Hanoi graphs", Dissertation, Ludwig-Maximilians-Universität München, 2016. [PDF](https://edoc.ub.uni-muenchen.de/20276/1/Holz_auf_der_Heide_Caroline.pdf)